# How to get only the priority from the entire JSON object in Bash Script?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to get the highest priority used for the application gateway rules. I can get the rules using the below command:

```
az network application-gateway rule list -g $resource_group_name --gateway-name $app_gateway_name
```

How can we retrieve the priority from that data in a bash script?

Comment: Please show us the JSON output from that command. Also, if you want Bash then please remove the `powershell` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use [jq tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), it requires installation, but it allows to manipulate JSON structures and even modify it.

I see that 'az' command also support JMESpath. So you can filter exactly what you need.

> --query JMESPath query string. See http://jmespath.org/ for more information and examples.

I didn't know what is output structure. So as example command can be look like this:

```
az network application-gateway rule list \
    -g $resource_group_name \
    --gateway-name $app_gateway_name \
    --query '[].priority | sort(@) | [0]'
```

Comment: `$AppGW = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "app_gateway_name" -ResourceGroupName "resource_group_name"`

`$Priority=(Get-AzApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule -ApplicationGateway $AppGW |
     Sort-Object -Property Priority |
     Select-Object Priority -Last 1).Priority + 10`

I am using this cmd in PowerShell to get the highest priority. I wanted to know how can I get this in a Bash script.